# Add to default parameter in Azure Devops template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a project that uses a template:

Extracted relevant part of the template:

```
parameters:
  - name: buildArguments
    type: string
    default: 'here are my default build arguments'
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      configuration: '${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}'
      arguments: '${{ parameters.buildArguments }}'
      projects: |
        ${{ parameters.buildProjectNames }}
```

I want to keep the default buildArguments string and just concatenate/add project specific parts to it. How can I do that?

Part of my project pipeline

```
- template: build/templates/MyTemplate.yml@templates
  parameters:
    buildArguments: defaultvalue + myProjectSpecificArgumentsHere
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `join` [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#functions):

```
arguments: ${{ join('DEFAULT-VALUE',parameters.buildProjectNames) }}
```

(remove the default value from the `parameters`).